# Getting the decimal number of a double

Tags: java, math

I am working with a cos value which is represented in double. So my bounds are between -1.0 and 1.0, however for my work I am simply ignoring all negative variables.

Now I'd like to get the decimal number of this double number (sorry I couldn't find the literature term of this operation)

Basically with examples:

Assume that input is 0.12 then this could be written as 1.2 * 10^-1, what I am expecting to get is just the part where it is 10^-1

Another example is 0.00351, which can be written as 3.51 * 10^-3, so the expected result is 10^-3

I have developed this algorithm below but it's kind of quick and dirty. I was wondering whether is there any mathematical trick to avoid using a loop.

```
double result = 1;
while (input < 1.0) {
   input *= 10.0;
   result /= 10.0;
}
```

Also the above doesn't handle if input is 0.

I am using Java for coding if that helps.

Comment: What should happen if the input is 0?

Comment: @user2357112 then the output should be 0.

Comment: What should happen if the input is negative?

Answer (score 3):

It appears you are looking for the base 10 exponent of the number - use [Math.log10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10%28double%29) to do this

```
 Math.log10(input)
```

e.g.

```
log10(100) = 2
log10(1e-5) = -5
```

etc.

You'll need to remember the base you've used (10 in this case)

Comment: Thanks but the output is not in the right form. Eg, it gives -3 instead of 0.001

Comment: In that case, just use [Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(input)))](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow) to get the closest power.

Comment: Not to mention `Math.log10(1.5) == 0.17609125905568124`, rather than `0`. You need to floor it. Also, it probably needs some sign twiddling to handle negative inputs.

Comment: Yes, OP will need to guard against `log(<= 0)`, possibly by extracting an absolute value prior to mangling.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Tester {

    public static double lowbase(double v) {
        return Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(v))));
    }   

    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println(lowbase(0.12));
        System.out.println(lowbase(0.00351));
        System.out.println(lowbase(0));
        System.out.println(lowbase(-1));
    }   

}
```

*Gives:*

```
0.1
0.001
0.0
1.0
```

The `abs` is for handling the negative numbers, you may fiddle with that for a different take on negatives.

Comment: Thanks but the output is not in the right form. Eg, it gives -3 instead of 0.001

Comment: Thanks, just out of curiosity, is this approach more efficient than mine? (It really matters because I require this calculation tens-hundreds thousands per second)

Comment: It should be, but you need to test it to make sure.

Comment: I did some tests and your code runs 3x faster than my code

Answer (score 1):

In case you are actually looking for strings such as `"10^-2"` (as you said that the expected result would be in this format).

```
public String getCientific(double input){
    int exp;
    exp = (int) java.lang.Math.floor(java.lang.Math.log10(input));
    return  "10^" + exp;
 }
```